# Is there a possibility to split a memory block or access it in the middle

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am looking for an option to "split" `allocated memory`, (previously allocated with `malloc`) to store some `objects of different type and size` in the parts.

I tried it just by moving `pointer` and keep the `memory block` as one part like:

```
int main()
{
   void* ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
   int*  ptr2 = (static_cast<int*>(ptr1) + sizeof(int));

   ptr1 = new (ptr1)int(5);
   ptr2 = new(ptr2) int(7);

   return 0;
}
```

(Yes there is no free(), I know but it is just an example)

The question is, is to move the `pointer adress` this way reliable and can be used under every c++ compiler?
Or is there a better possibility to do this or even one to split the `memory block` in several parts.

(I neither want to use an `array` nor to use 3 times `new`/`malloc` and please no answers like "why should you want to do that?!" I want to do exactly that...)

Comment: You allocated it, so you are free to read/write to it. But I would strongly discourage doing it, if only for readability alone.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve after you have successfully "split" this memory?

Comment: I would suggest you use a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) if you want a heterogeneous container

Comment: Well, It's just for playing around with pointer and memory a bit to learn about it. I want to allocate a big block of memory in the beginning of my program to avoid allocating new memory during the "runtime".

Comment: Your `ptr2` points outside of the array (you added `sizeof(int)` instead of `1`)

Answer (score 1):

#### Homogeneous container

Use an `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr;
arr[0] = 5;
arr[1] = 7;
arr[2] = 9;
```

no need for dynamic allocation, nor manual memory management. This way you have contiguous memory and easy access to each element. Not only that, but you get standard compliant code for free.

If you really need dynamic allocation (because for example your code uses heavy objects), then just use `std::vector` as follows:

```
std::vector<int> arr(3);
arr[0] = 5;
arr[1] = 7;
arr[2] = 9;
```

I know. Too good to be true.

---

#### Heterogeneous container

On the other hand, if you want a container of different sizes, you can use `std::tuple`, like:

```
std::tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3, ...> tuple;
```

---

#### Variant

And finally, if what you are trying to achieve is something like a `union`, seeing your comment:

> to store some objects of different type and size in the parts.

then you can use `boost::variant` instead, which will allow you to store efficiently, objects of different types in the same memory location.

If you don't know all possible types in advance (at compile time), then it's probably a good idea to use `boost::any`.

Comment: TS asked  to store objects of different type and size
it's more about tuple - not array

Comment: Point one, arrays won't solve my problem, i want to store different types in the memory block so your answer sadly won't work (only with an array of any classes but that's not the solution I wish). The other point is that I explicit wrote i don't want an array. (Still thanks for the answer)

Comment: @Mango Have you read about `std::tuple` and `boost::variant`?

Comment: About `std::tuple` not now, `boost::variant` is well known to me but I don't like the idea because it is a bit slow i think. Sorry I'm working on looking over all answers, my upper answere only refers to the array, vector part of your answer I am going to read about the `std::tuple` option.

Comment: What makes variants slow, @Mango? (Hint: it all depends on use patterns)

Comment: the internal code (a lot of casting and typechecks) which has to be executed(for good reasons of course), automatic datatypes always are paid in speed. I don't know if I can do it faster but I'm going to try it I already wrote an any class which is faster than boost::any, I don't know if it's better ( well, I doubt it) but as far as I can test it, its performance  is better than the performance of boost::any and boost::variant. And both, any and variant aren't wrote on performance so they don't even try to be fast.

Comment: @Mango Can I see this implementation and your benchmarks? I'm really curious now.

Comment: There is how I tested it, my Any class and how accurate I think it is. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88772/variant-class-named-any-like-in-boostany

Answer (score 1):

> is to move the pointer adress this way reliable and can be used under every c++ compiler?

Yes, with a couple of caveats:

- each pointer must be correctly aligned for the type you're creating there. The base address, obtained from `malloc`, will be correctly aligned for any type, so just make sure each offset is a multiple of that type's alignment requirement.
- types with non-trivial destructors should be manually destroyed after use.

However, you've messed up the pointer arithmetic in your example: you cast to `int`, then add `sizeof(int)` to the pointer. The result is that you're adding 16 bytes rather than the expected 4 (assuming a 4-byte `int` type), taking you beyond the end of the allocation. Cast to `char*` if you want to deal with byte offsets.

> is there a better possibility to do this

If the layout is known at compile time, then just use a `struct` or possibly a `tuple`. If not, then this is probably your only moderately sensible option.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, is to move the pointer adress this way reliable and can be used under every c++ compiler?

Answer: yes, a few ways

```
// p points to 3 ints
int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int) * 3));

int* p_plus_1 = p + 1;  // the '1' is automatically scaled by the size of an int
*p_plus_1 = 10;

// demonstrate equivalence
assert(*(p+1) == *p_plus_1);
assert((p+1) == p_plus_1);
assert((p+1) == &p[1]);
assert(*p_plus_1 == p[1]);
```

> Or is there a better possibility to do this or even one to split the memory block in several parts.

Answer: depends on what you're trying to achieve. Need more info.

Comment: Thanks, this answer looks interesting. To the more info point: I want to minimize the amount of new allocations during runtime but want the opportunity to store really big objects if nessecery so the splits should possibly be undone. But on the other hand I don't want to waste the memory when I don't store big objects that's why I want it partwise, to also store smaller objects.

Comment: You're writing a memory allocator. `new` and `delete` already do this for you extremely efficiently :)

Comment: Yep I know what I'm trying to do :) I already read some ideas for an allocator but I think I would like to try a new opportunity for training. How I mentioned above, it is to learn about pointers and memory :)

Comment: ok, here's the original K&R memory allocator. It's a good starting point: http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/2.x/src/lib/libc/malloc.c